# imageMagick convert from a folder to another command in Linux?

Tags: linux, imagemagick

I have the two folders under the same level directory
folder1 and folder 2
now I try to convert all images in folder1 to folder2 and with same file name.
here is what i have now:

```
 for f in folder1/*.jpg
 do 
       convert $f  -resize 80%X80% +profile "*" -quality 85 folder2/$f
 done
```

and it throws the following message from each file it tried to convert:
convert: unable to open image `folder1/folder2/st-3474827-1.jpg': No such file or directory @ blob.c/OpenBlob/2440.

and I know its directory problem but google for two days already still dont know how to fix it. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Do any of the filenames contains spaces?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's two ways you could deal with it.

1. Use `mogrify`:

   ```
   mogrify -path folder2 -thumbnail 50x50 folder1/*.jpg
   ```
2. Use `basename`:

   ```
   for filename in folder1/*.jpg; do
       basename="$(basename "$filename" .jpg)"
       convert "folder1/$basename.jpg" -thumbnail 50x50 "folder2/$basename.jpg"
   done
   ```

The former option is probably better, but the latter may be clearer.

Comment: @shakabra: I actually had no idea about the `-path` option until you posted it in your answer, so thank you for that. I saw it, tested it, and integrated it into my answer.

Comment: Your second example using basename worked fine for me only after I removed the quotation marks surrounding the definition of basename variable and those surrounding the options for convert. I've tested it on fedora with either sh and bash.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a couple of wrong answers. Sorry I just assumed that mogrify or convert would behave well with outputting to a different path. Shouldn't assume. I don't know if Imagemagick can output to a different directory. You may have to just mv the output(no suggestions here) to the new directory. I tried this( I was trying to be as simple as possible without any loops...

```
convert -resize 500x500 * ../test2/ #output was 2 files named -0 -1 in the new dir
mogrify -resize 200x150 ~/Pictures/rome/test/*.jpg -path  ~/Pictures/rome/test2/ # gotta *.jpg in new dir YAY!
mogrify -resize 200x150 -path ~/Pictures/rome/test2/*.jpg ~/Pictures/rome/test/*.jpg # blob error
```

The manpages don't mention output to a new directory and I searched around a little. The exception codes for ImageMagick are [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/exception.php) Good luck and sorry for the faulty gouge. I will edit if I find anything new.